# 金額の、正規表現の書き方

Tags: 正規表現

「￥1,800 のパン」というものの正規表現を教えてください。1,800のあとにはスペースが入っています。

Comment: /￥1,800 のパン/
でどうでしょう。 さておき、おそらく一致させたいパターンがいくつかあると想像しますので、そちらを列挙していただけますか。

Comment: ￥1,800 のパン
￥900 のパン
￥100,000のパン
等のパターンが挙げられます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`￥\d{1,3}(,\d{3})* のパン`
ではいかがですか？

『￥100,000のパン』だけ金額と『の』の間にスペース無いですが、あるという前提でいいですよね？

Comment: はい。あるという前提で大丈夫です。