# 金額の、正規表現の書き方:数字の前の0（ゼロ）を削除する方法

Tags: 正規表現

￥01,900のパン →￥1,900のパン
￥0,900のパン →￥900のパン
にする方法を教えてください。
「数字のカンマを外して、数字の前の0を削除して、数字の3桁毎のカンマを付ける」以外の方法がありますか？
よろしくお願いします。

[金額の、正規表現の書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23609/%e9%87%91%e9%a1%8d%e3%81%ae-%e6%ad%a3%e8%a6%8f%e8%a1%a8%e7%8f%be%e3%81%ae%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e6%96%b9)
（参考）正規表現で数字の前の0（ゼロ）を削除する方法
http://www.php-mysql-linux.com/regular-expression/no0/

Comment: 正規表現の問題（練習）としてはよさそうにも感じますが、本当に解きたい問題は別にあったりしないでしょうか？ `￥0,900のパン` というデータができてしまう過程の段階でこのようなデータができてしまわないようにしたほうがいいと思います。また質問文にはありませんが、 `￥0,000,900のパン` といった 0がもっと連続したパターンもあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perlなら、こうすればたぶん十分です。

```
my $price = "￥01,900";
$price =~ s/￥(0+,?)*/￥/;
```

(携帯を使っていますので、試すことができません)

例外: `￥0のパン`に不対応。

Comment: `￥0のパン` にも対応する場合は `$price =~ s/￥0+,?(?=.+)/￥/;` とすればよろしいかと。

Comment: `$price =~ s/￥0+,?(?=.+)/￥/;`だと￥0は救えますが、"￥0,002"の場合のゼロサプレスが不十分のようです。

Comment: @akiraejiri `"￥0,002"` という表記に意味があるとは思えませんが、その場合は、`$price =~ s/￥[0,]+(?=(.+))/￥/;` とすれば良いでしょう。

Comment: @metropolis 確かに"￥0,002"には意味がないですね。

Comment: ￥0,002のパンは、入力の確認、チェックに使います。

Comment: タブレットアンドロイド環境:で、http://codepad.org/ でできました。

Answer (score 1):

> 「数字のカンマを外して、数字の前の0を削除して、数字の3桁毎のカンマを付ける」以外の方法がありますか？

`￥`に続く`0`と`,`を削除する(マッチする条件から外す)方法が考えられます。

例1　`￥`に続く`0`と`,`を削除する`sed`の例

```
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*/￥/' <<< "￥01,900"
￥1,900
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*/￥/' <<< "￥0,900"
￥900
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*/￥/' <<< "￥00,000,012"
￥12
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*\(.*\)/￥\1/' <<< "￥000"
￥
```

例2　`￥`に続く`0`と`,`をマッチする条件から外す`sed`の例

```
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*\(.*\)/￥\1/' <<< "￥01,900"
￥1,900
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*\(.*\)/￥\1/' <<< "￥0,900"
￥900
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*\(.*\)/￥\1/' <<< "￥00,000,012"
￥12
$ sed 's/^￥[0,]*\(.*\)/￥\1/' <<< "￥000"
￥
```

いずれの方法も0の場合単独の`￥`になってしまいます。
結果に対して単独の`￥`を`￥0`に置換すればいいのですが、いっぺんに対応する方法は思いつきませんでした。